# Create a variable based on the order on a specific value of another variable

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe similar to this (although more complex):

```
id <- rep(1:2, each = 4)
Cond <- rep(c("test", "test","form", "form", "form", "form", "test","test"))

df <- data.frame(id,Cond)
```

I would like to create a third variable in my dataframe that tells me the order of Cond for each ID. For example, the first participants had first the test and then the form.  In the end, the dataframe would look like this:

```
 id Cond order
  1 test test-form
  1 test test-form
  1 form test-form
  1 form test-form
  2 form form-test
  2 form form-test
  2 test form-test
  2 test form-test
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can check the first element of each 'id' to `paste` the 'form' or 'test'

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(order = str_c(first(Cond), setdiff(c('form', 'test'), 
               first(Cond)), sep='-'))
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   id [2]
#     id Cond  order    
#  <int> <fct> <chr>    
#1     1 test  test-form
#2     1 test  test-form
#3     1 form  test-form
#4     1 form  test-form
#5     2 form  form-test
#6     2 form  form-test
#7     2 test  form-test
#8     2 test  form-test
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Unfortunately, that code doesn't give you the output that I want.  For example, for the id 1, your ouput gives this sequence test-form, test-form, form-test, form-test. And for this particpants all should be test-form